# Hook Chrome debugger up to text editor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Is there some way to get chrome to launch my text editor when I click on a stack trace link pointing to a file:// url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the only way to achieve this is to modify DevTools front-end code(it's HTML+JavaScript so it shouldn't be too hard) to customize link clicks handling. There is a WebKit feature request for this functionality: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51526

Answer (score 2):

If you have relatively many files, you could try the Eclipse-based project:
http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/

If you manage to set up source lookup, you will have debugger stepping over your working files and live editing.
Together with JSDT or Aptana installed this may be quite usable.

However you will get only JS debugger, DOM tree is not supported.

Comment: +1 That's cool.  But I don't think it's cool enough to get me to switch development environments.